# Create an empty Column without blank space

Tags: python, pysimplegui

In my PySimpleGUI app I create empty Col's, which I add items into later on. However, when I add these empty Col's to the app, there is this large blank space underneath them which makes the app's height unnecessarily large.

I am currently creating the empty Column with just an empty Text, because without anything in the Column there is an error. However, I believe this is the reason there is a gap, because it is creating space for this Text element which isn't meant to be there. Are there any empty elements that I can put here instead?

Here's an example of adding the empty sg.Col

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text('Basic Information:')],
             [sg.Text('Test App', size=(15,1))],
             
             [sg.Col([[sg.T('', size=(0,0))]], key='-TESTCOL-')],

             [sg.Text('Underneath the large gap', size=(15,1))]

while True:
    window = sg.Window('Test App', layout)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no any element with size (0, 0).

To remove the space occupied by a element, you can do it by setting the option `vaisible=False`, also use the `pin` helper function to cause containers to shrink to fit the contents correct after something inside has changed visiblity .

> Pin's an element provided into a layout so that when it's made invisible and visible again, it will
> be in the correct place.  Otherwise it will be placed at the end of its containing window/column.
>
> The element you want to pin is the element that you'll be making visibile/invisible.
>
> The pin helper function also causes containers to shrink to fit the contents correct after something inside has changed visiblity.  Note that setting a hardcoded size on your window can impact this ability to shrink.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Basic Information:')],
    [sg.Text('Test App', size=(15,1))],
    [sg.pin(sg.Column([[]], visible=False, key='-TESTCOL-'))],
    [sg.Text('Underneath the large gap', size=(15,1))],
    [sg.Button('Show'), sg.Button('Hide')]
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Show':
        window['-TESTCOL-'].update(visible=True)
    elif event == 'Hide':
        window['-TESTCOL-'].update(visible=False)

window.close()
```